# Get Client IP during Logging in

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication

So I have a static method to get the client IP using `HttpContext`.

```
public static string GetClientMachineIPAddress()
    {
        string strClientIP = string.Empty;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null ||!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
        {
            strClientIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
        if (strClientIP == string.Empty)
        {
            strClientIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        }
        return strClientIP;
    }
```

This works fine when the user is already logged in, but doesn't work if i try to get IP during logging in since `HttpContext.Current` is null before a session is established.

Any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Below method is the way I get the IP Address. HttpContext.Current shouldn't be empty even if you do not have session. I suspect something else is causing the error though.

```
string ipaddress;
ipaddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (ipaddress == "" || ipaddress == null)
   ipaddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
return ipaddress;
```